# how to hide the content managment tab from left menu in oracle webcenter content (UCM)?

Tags: oracle, webcenter, oracle-ucm

[image]
I want to hide the content management tab from the left side menu shown on the picture for a specific user how to achieve that?
I've tried to change the permission for that user to R (Read)  only and content management was hidden.
but the problem is when I do that, this user can't add any attachments to a document, which is an undesired behavior

Answer (score 0):

Add &coreContentOnly=1 to the url

Comment: but how i will force the user to always use this url ?

Comment: That is fairly easy, if you have opened the magic box "Custom components". If you haven't, then you have quite a bit of preparation to do. It is well worth the effort if you are doing customization of WCC though. I can give you some more details if you think this is the way to go.

Comment: yes, please 
I have 5 users, and I want this menu item only visible for one of them

Comment: First of all, make sure you can run Component Wizard. It is installed on the server and you will have to run it there. The way to do it differs depending on your environment. I will try to show you some example code that will get you started.
I also just realized that I misunderstood your question. My first answer removes all navigation and you just wanted a specific tray to go away. That is slightly trickier, but still doable with a custom component.

Comment: Here is a lot of valuable information on the subject: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/wcc/webcenter-content-develop/look_nav.htm

Comment: I'm trying to resolve the X11 problem, to be able to run the componentWizard through SSH.
Anyway, Thanks for the Url, what I've understand that I will create a custom template and use some of the booleans that are there to show the link only to a specific user .
i'm I getting it right ?

Comment: it's enabled now , I'm looking forward for more links from you sir, as the subject is still vague to me, also I will need to hide some actions from the workflow action menu (for specific users) , thanks.